In a place vs On a place

The line between life and death is a dangerous place to be on.

Vs

The line between life and death is a dangerous place to be in.

You would be on a line, street, border etc. But you are always in a place. I have never heard of : "He was on a place....." It sounds wrong.
Which is correct?
I was writing something and this sentence puzzled me.

Just leave it as "...a dangerous place to be."

Or 'Being on the road from Aix to Ghent was dangerous.' So on.  Various other questions have addressed the on/in/at question for locations, maps, documents and the like. But 'Being on the line from Aix to Ghent was dangerous' sounds very unnatural. The actual noun involved makes a big difference.

That's because the "on" refers to the line and not the place...The line |between x and y| is a dangerous place to be on. But you could indeed leave it out.

What @KillingTime said. It's not particularly idiomatic to include any preposition in the exact cited context (but if you insist on having one, you'd be at a place, not in or on it). But discarding place and resequencing  to It's dangerous to be on the line between x and y I personally wouldn't be likely to use in, but apparently some people do.

@EdwinAshworth I was using it more like : "The line between life and death..."

@FumbleFingers I went for that in the beginning. Then I had a feeling it needs a preposition. Lol

Well, in your version, the referent is a [dangerous] place, not the line. But it's all a bit confusing, because a line is usually a continuous series of overlapping places, not a single place that you could be "at". It might have helped if you'd pointed out at the start that you were thinking of the metaphorical line between the states of life and death, rather than "literal" places designated as x and y.

To be on a line: He was on the line between two squares. on a line

The actual noun involved makes a big difference, as stated above. It is important (in nearly all cases) to give an actual example (or several) that doesn't / don't involve the over-general 'x/y'. // Closed as a duplicate ... but do say if you feel your exact example isn't addressed there. FumbleFingers (above) particularises here for the case involving 'line'.

@FF Checking the G ngram hits: most seem to refer to 'the line' in the military sense ('front line'). Others are in legal documents. I'd say 'in the line' is rare for more everyday uses.

@EdwinAshworth should I edit the question  ?

@FumbleFingers ⬆️

This ELL question discusses when "on a place" is acceptable. It seems that if the verb and other elements strongly suggest "on", then it's OK to use.

I think 'He was/found himself Ø the fine line between life and death.' (where Ø = 'on' or 'in') might stand a better chance, though I'd suggest using a verbal ing-form instead ('He found himself walking/treading [/negotiating]  [/facing] the fine line between life and death.') But 'in a fine line' isn't good for 'on a [fine] line'; it speaks of constituting a line ('The soldiers were in a fine line and looked well drilled.')

Well, if X and Y are "life" and "death", it's a bit trite to say the line between life and death is a dangerous place to be. Anyway, life starts at conception (or birth, or whatever), so it's not clear whether that should be understood as meaning being alive at all is inherently dangerous, or just being near death is dangerous. (But presumably, never having been born at all is the least dangerous state! :)
